# Calling functions such as startActivity() inside of an enum

Tags: android, enums, android-dialogfragment

I wanted to centralise the creation of DialogFragments used to report errors to the user in order to just have a class to which I pass the error code and have the dialog spawned automagically.

In order to handle multiple errors I am using an enum in which I define the error propreties.

```
public enum DialogError {

  TTS_NOT_INSTALLED {
    @Override
    public int getTitleResource() {
      return R.string.error_tts_not_installed_title;
    }
    @Override
    public int getMessageResource() {
      return R.string.error_tts_not_installed_message;
    }
    @Override
    public int getPositiveButtonResource() {
      return R.string.error_tts_not_installed_button_positive;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPositiveButtonClick() {
      // TODO
    }
    @Override
    public int getNegativeButtonResource() {
      return R.string.error_tts_not_installed_button_negative;
    }
    @Override
    public void onNegativeButtonClick() {
      // TODO
    }
  };

  public abstract int getTitleResource();
  public abstract int getMessageResource();
  public abstract int getPositiveButtonResource();
  public abstract void onPositiveButtonClick();
  public abstract int getNegativeButtonResource();
  public abstract void onNegativeButtonClick();

}
```

Then I have my FragmentDialogError class that I call to create a new Dialog.

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class FragmentDialogError
    extends DialogFragment {

  Context context;
  DialogError error;

  public FragmentDialogError(Context context, DialogError error) {
    this.context = context;
    this.error = error;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  @Override
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder
        .setTitle(error.getTitleResource())
        .setMessage(error.getMessageResource())
        .setPositiveButton(error.getPositiveButtonResource(),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            error.onPositiveButtonClick();
          }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(error.getNegativeButtonResource(),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            error.onNegativeButtonClick();
          }
        });
    return builder.create();
  }

}
```

My problem now is that I can't obviously call functions such as startActivity inside of my enum's onPositiveButtonClick() or onNegativeButtonClick().

One soluction would be using a switch() in FragmentDialogError but this way I would split the code between the enum and the class. Another one would be to define in some way the actions that a button press could trigger and let handle them to another class, but I'm looking for a clean and elegant soluction.

How can I implement this in Java keeping the code tidy?

Comment: You can, if you provide `Context` parameter for the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add a Context to the onClick handlers that you can use to do startActivity?

Also, instead of overriding all the methods in your enum why not use members and a constructor?

```
public enum DialogError {

  TTS_NOT_INSTALLED(
    R.string.error_tts_not_installed_title,
    R.string.error_tts_not_installed_message,
    R.string.error_tts_not_installed_button_positive,
    R.string.error_tts_not_installed_button_negative) {

    public void onPositiveButtonClick(Context context) {
      context.startActivity...
    }

    @Override
    public void onNegativeButtonClick(Context context) {
      // TODO
    }
  };

  private final int mTitle;
  private final int mMessage;
  private final int mPositive;
  private final int mNegative;

  private DialogError(int title, int message, int positive, int negative) {
      mTitle = title;
      mMessage = message;
      mPositive = positive;
      mNegative = negative;
  }

  public final int getTitleResource() {
      return mTitle;
  }
  public final int getMessageResource() {
      return mMessage;
  }
  public final int getPositiveButtonResource() {
      return mPositive;
  }
  public final int getNegativeButtonResource() {
      return mNegative;
  }

  public abstract void onPositiveButtonClick();
  public abstract void onNegativeButtonClick();

}
```